# BigQuery Storage gRPC-Web: Got 404 error while creating a read session

Tags: javascript, google-bigquery, grpc

*New updates at the end.*

We are creating a BigQuery Storage library in JavaScript for browsers.

The problem we are facing is that we obtain a 404 error from `https://bigquerystorage.googleapis.com/`:

[image: 404 camouflaged as CORS]

It looks like a CORS problem, but it really is a 404 one:

```sh
$> curl 'https://bigquerystorage.googleapis.com/google.cloud.bigquery.storage.v1beta1.BigQueryStorage/CreateReadSession' \
       -H 'x-goog-request-params: table_reference.project_id=project&table_reference.dataset_id=dataset' \
       -H 'X-User-Agent: grpc-web-javascript/0.1' -H 'DNT: 1' -H 'Content-Type: application/grpc-web-text' \
       -H 'Accept: application/grpc-web-text' -H 'X-Grpc-Web: 1' -H 'Sec-Fetch-Dest: empty' \
       --data-binary 'ydG9k_binary_data_oATgB' --compressed

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang=en>
  <meta charset=utf-8>
  <meta name=viewport content="initial-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width">
  <title>Error 404 (Not Found)!!1</title>
...
```

Any idea what is happening with the request?

Here are all the resources we are using. This is the base structure:

[image: project structure]

The original `.proto` files come from:

- `src/proto/google/api/`: https://github.com/googleapis/googleapis
- `src/proto/google/cloud/bigquery/storage/v1beta1/`: https://github.com/googleapis/python-bigquery-storage
- `src/proto/google/protobuf/`: https://github.com/protocolbuffers/protobuf

For compiling the `.proto` into the `.js` ones we use `protoc` and the `protoc-gen-grpc-web` plugin with:

```sh
cd src/proto/
protoc -I=. $(find . -iname "*.proto") --js_out=import_style=commonjs:. --grpc-web_out=import_style=commonjs,mode=grpcwebtext:.
```

And finally, this is the `big_query_storage.js` file that we bundle with `rollup.js`:

```js
import BigQueryStorage from './proto/storage_grpc_web_pb.js';
import BigQueryStorageEnums from './proto/storage_pb.js';
import TableComponents from './proto/google/cloud/bigquery/storage/v1beta1/table_reference_pb.js';
import Timestamp from 'google-protobuf/google/protobuf/timestamp_pb.js';

const bigQueryStorageHostname = 'https://bigquerystorage.googleapis.com'

const projectId = 'project';
const datasetId = 'dataset';
const tableId = 'table';

const fields = ['column'];
const rowRestriction = 'where';

function BigQueryStorageTest() {
  let client = new BigQueryStorage.BigQueryStorageClient(bigQueryStorageHostname);

  let tableReference = new TableComponents.TableReference();
  tableReference.setProjectId(projectId);
  tableReference.setDatasetId(datasetId);
  tableReference.setTableId(tableId);

  let readOptions = new TableComponents.TableReadOptions();
  readOptions.setSelectedFieldsList(fields);
  readOptions.setRowRestriction(rowRestriction);

  const parent = `projects/${projectId}`;

  let readSessionRequest = new BigQueryStorage.CreateReadSessionRequest();
  readSessionRequest.setTableReference(tableReference);
  readSessionRequest.setParent(parent);
  readSessionRequest.setReadOptions(readOptions);
  readSessionRequest.setFormat(BigQueryStorageEnums.DataFormat.AVRO);
  readSessionRequest.setShardingStrategy(BigQueryStorageEnums.ShardingStrategy.LIQUID);

  let metadata = {};

  let routingHeader = new URLSearchParams({
    'table_reference.project_id': encodeURI(tableReference.getProjectId()),
    'table_reference.dataset_id': encodeURI(tableReference.getDatasetId())
  }).toString();

  let routingMetadata = {
    'x-goog-request-params': routingHeader
  };

  metadata = {...metadata, ...routingMetadata}

  let session = client.createReadSession(readSessionRequest, metadata);
}

export default BigQueryStorageTest;
```

**UPDATE 1:**

It looks the Big Query Storage API doesn't support gRPC calls in text mode. Text mode set the `Content-Type` header to `application/grpc-web-text` and the body as binary encoded in base64.

So, because of that, the API can't find the table in the encoded body, returning a 404 error.

Modifying the compiled `.js` files (from the `.proto`) for using binary as format, the body is sent as binary and the `Content-Type` header is set to `application/x-protobuf`. This works as the API doesn't return a 404 error, but a 400 is received, `Invalid resource field value in the request`.

**UPDATE 2:**

There is a new BigQuery Storage library for Node.js https://github.com/googleapis/nodejs-bigquery-storage, which works like a charm in Node.js, obviously, but it has some problem when ported to browsers.

It looks that it can't perform stream operations, and gives this error when accessing the generated stub for the `readRows` service:

```
TypeError: undefined is not a function
    at Service.newServiceStub.<computed> [as readRows] (fallback.js:190)
    at big_query_storage_client.js:147
    at streamingApiCaller.js:37
    at timeout.js:43
    at Object.request (streaming.js:102)
    at makeRequest (index.js:128)
    at retryRequest (index.js:96)
    at StreamProxy.setStream (streaming.js:93)
    at StreamingApiCaller.call (streamingApiCaller.js:53)
    at createApiCall.js:72
```

Comment: As you mentioned that it can be a real 404, and 404 means [Not Found](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/error-messages#sample-error-response). Do you have the resource that was not found in BigQuery? It usually comes within the error response like shown in the previous link.

Comment: Hi @rsantiago. Yes the resource exists :(

Comment: It is worth of distinguishing between BQ resources (initially I thought on dataset or table resources), and the CORS resource the error refers: 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin header is present on the requested *resource*'. Since the resource exists in BQ, have you explored the posibility this is a real CORS issue? AFAIK, you can check the request/response headers and look for the Origin.